# Python 3 exercise: generating permutation

Tags: python-3.x, generator, yield

I am trying to write a generator function for permutation for practice. But it does not return anything.
But if I replace 
´´yield new[k]´´ with ´´lis.append(new[k])´´, then I get the correct list of permutations. Am I doing something wrong with yield?

```
tup=(1,2,3) # tup can be any sequence
new=[[]]*(len(tup)+1) # memory; new[0]=[], new[1] will be length 1 permutation, etc.
lis=[]  # the list of permutations

def repeat(k): # recursion
    for i in tup:
        if i in new[k-1]:
            continue # permutation can't repeat
        else: new[k]=new[k-1]+[i]

        if k==len(tup): 
             yield new[k]
        else:
             repeat(k+1)

gen=repeat(1)
for i in gen:
    print(i)
```

Comment: what is wrong with tabs?

Comment: They break the formatting. They can only be used with much care, and it's not worth it. Never have a tab in a source file, ever. If you need to put a tab in some text, write it like `'\t'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a recursive function, but you don't pass on the value from the recursion, which is why it doesn't return anything.

You need to change the call to

```
repeat(k+1)
```

to

```
for x in repeat(k+1):
    yield x
```

The resulting function is then:

```
tup=(1,2,3) # tup can be any sequence
new=[[]]*(len(tup)+1) # memory; new[0]=[], new[1] will be length 1 permutation, etc.
lis=[]  # the list of permutations

def repeat(k): # recursion
    for i in tup:
        if i in new[k-1]:
            continue # permutation can't repeat
        else: new[k]=new[k-1]+[i]

        if k==len(tup): 
             yield new[k]
        else:
             for x in repeat(k+1):
                 yield x

for i in repeat(1):
    print(i)
```

Which works.

The next step is then to get rid of the global variables.

Comment: Thank you.  By getting rid of the global variables, do you mean  defining another function like permutation(tup) and enclose those variables inside the definition of this function?

Comment: @user1470575: Well, I mean enclose the variables inside the existing `repeat()` function. But that's not always the correct solution, but another wrapper function is rarely correct. Sometimes a class is a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to write an algorithm for generating permutations of multiple lengths using generators for practice.

Try this question on for size:
[How to generate all permutations of a list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104420/how-to-generate-all-permutations-of-a-list-in-python)

You'll need to translate to python3, which shouldn't be that big an issue.

Unfortunately, I think your problem lies in your algorithm, rather than your use of `yield`, which looks okay to me.

Comment: I am storing permutation of shorter length because after generating one full length permutation, I just want to increment the last entry(s) to generate a new full length permutation